# Rails ActionView::MissingTemplate, Template Is Missing for mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, actionmailer, mailer

I have a mailer class called ContactUsMailer that inherits from ActionMailer::Base.

```
class ContactUsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'myemail@gmail.com'

  def contact_us(name:, email:, message:)
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @message = message
    mail(
      to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
      subject: "New email inquiry from #{@name} (#{@email})",
      template_path: 'views/mailers/contact_us_mailer',
      template_name: 'contact_us'
    )
  end
end
```

It is being called from the ContactUsController.

```
class ContactUsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def create
    if params[:name].blank? || params[:email].blank? || params[:message].blank?
      flash[:error] = "Your name, email, and a message are required. Please try again."
    else
      ContactUsMailer.contact_us(
        name: params[:name],
        email: params[:email],
        message: params[:message]
      ).deliver!

      flash[:notice] = "Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly."
    end

    redirect_to contact_us_path
  end

  private

end
```

My mailer templates exist under views/mailers/contact_us_mailer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      New inquiry from <%= @name %>
    </p>
    <p>
      Email: <%= @email %>
    </p>
    ---------
    Message: <%= @message %>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I do not add `body:` to the `mail()` call in `ContactUsMailer`, I receive the following error:

```
Template is missing
Missing template views/mailers/contact_us_mailer/contact_us with "mailer". Searched in: * "views/mailers/contact_us_mailer"
```

If I DO add `body: @message` to the `mail()` call, I receive no errors and the email sends successfully, however the email contains only the message and not the template itself.

I do not understand why Rails is failing to recognize the template, even when I specify a path.  Digging into the `collect_responses_from_templates(headers)` method, it clearly recognizes the template data in the headers.

```
def collect_responses_from_templates(headers)
=> 986:         templates_path = headers[:template_path] || self.class.mailer_name
   987:         templates_name = headers[:template_name] || action_name
   988: 
   989:         each_template(Array(templates_path), templates_name).map do |template|
   990:           format = template.format || self.formats.first
(byebug) headers[:template_path]
"views/mailers/contact_us_mailer"
```

Any advice for how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try it to do it in this format

`mail( to: 'myemail@gmail.com', subject: "New email inquiry from #{@name} (#{@email})") do |format| format.mjml format.text end `

should get the template in a dynamic way instead to set the configuration in the mailer.

Comment: I've done so and unfortunately I'm still receiving a missing template error.

`Missing template contact_us_mailer/contact_us`

Comment: What is your view file named?

Comment: Figured it out.  I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

I tried regenerating the mailer via `bundle exec rails generate mailer contact_us` and noticed that it created a mailer at `app/mailers/contact_us_mailer.rb` .. My original mailer was located at `app/mailers/contact_us_mailer/`.  Something about having the namespaced path must have been throwing off the Rails magic.